# Non-deterministic crash in BlocksKit bk_apply block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a function that constructs an `NSMutableDictionary` using [`bk_apply`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/BlocksKit/2.0.0/Categories/NSSet+BlocksKit.html#//api/name/bk_apply:), a method provided by the third-party block utility library [BlocksKit](https://github.com/zwaldowski/BlocksKit). The function's test suite usually passes just fine, but once every couple runs it crashes.

```
NSMutableDictionary *result = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[inputSet bk_apply:^(NSString *property) {
    NSString *localValueName = propertyToLocalName[property];
    NSObject *localValue = [self valueForKey:localValueName];

    result[property] = localValue ?: defaults[property];                // Crash

    // Convert all dates in result to ISO 8601 strings
    if ([result[property] isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) {              // Crash
        result[property] = ((NSDate *)result[property]).ISODateString;  // Crash
    }

}];
```

The crash always happens on a line where `result` is referenced, but it's not the same line every time.

Examining the contents of `result` in the debugger, I've seen very strange values like

```
po result
{
    val1 = "Some reasonable value";
    val2 = "Also reasonable value";
    (null) = (null);
}
```

It's impossible for an `NSDictionary` to have `null` keys or values, so clearly some invariant is being violated.

What is causing this crash and how do I fix it?

Comment: Good call, I assumed the `bk_` suite of functions had more name recognition than they do in fact

Comment: Initially I thought it might be a memory management issue. But yes, you are essentially correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the BlocksKit [documentation](https://github.com/zwaldowski/BlocksKit/blob/master/BlocksKit/Core/NSArray%2BBlocksKit.h#L37) for `bk_apply`:

> Enumeration will occur on appropriate background queues. This will
>   have a noticeable speed increase, especially on dual-core devices, but
>   you *must* be aware of the thread safety of the objects you message
>   from within the block.

The code above is highly unsafe with respect to threading, because it reads from and writes to a mutable variable on multiple threads.

The intermittent nature of the crash comes from the fact that the [thread scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)) is non-deterministic. The crash won't happen when several threads accessing shared memory *happen* to have their execution scheduled in sequence rather than in parallel. It is therefore possible to "get lucky" some or even most of the time, but the code is still wrong.

---

The debugger printout is a good example of the danger. The thread that's paused is most likely reading from `result` while another thread performs an insertion.

`NSMutableDictionary` insertions are likely not atomic; example steps might be,

1. allocate memory for the new entry
2. copy the entry's key into the memory
3. copy the entry's value into the memory

If you read the dictionary from another thread between steps **1** and **2**, you will see an entry for which memory has been allocated, but the memory contains no values.

---

The simplest fix is to switch to [`bk_each`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/BlocksKit/2.0.0/Categories/NSSet+BlocksKit.html#//api/name/bk_each:). `bk_each` does the same thing as `bk_apply` but it's implemented in a way that guarantees sequential execution.